# Angular 12: Warning: 1 rules skipped due to selector errors:

Tags: angular

В Angular 12 при построении проекта выдаётся такое вот предупреждение:

```
Warning: 1 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap);
@font-face -> Unmatched selector: ;1,400;1,700&display=swap);
@font-face
```

@font-face у меня в css файле со шрифтами ionicons.min.css, вот он:

```
@font-face{font-family:"Ionicons";src:url("../fonts/ionicons.eot?v=4.5.10-1");src:url("../fonts/ionicons.eot?v=4.5.10-1#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),url("../fonts/ionicons.woff2?v=4.5.10-1") format("woff2"),url("../fonts/ionicons.woff?v=4.5.10-1") format("woff"),url("../fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=4.5.10-1") format("truetype"),url("../fonts/ionicons.svg?v=4.5.10-1#Ionicons") format("svg");font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}
```

Путь к файлу объявлен в стилях в angular.json

Вопрос: что это за предупреждение, и что нужно исправить, чтобы его не было?